# Find a significant diff in sql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a small server where data is collected from remote battery operated nodes on a SQL database(MySQL). Battery voltage is also collected, and a full battery is around 4.2V, a low battery where node stops sending is around 2.7V .
When I replace a dead battery ofcourse the node starts sending again and it's battery level goes to 4.2V. I would like to run a query that detects this transition. Nodes have a unique id(node_id), and each row in the table has a unique id(idx). In other words find 2 consequent rows for a node where bbattery jumped from ~2.7(idx) to ~4,2(idx+n) where n is any positive number and represents other rows that were stored between idx and idx+n, by other nodes.
Thank you

Comment: Please read through [how to create minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then edit this question so it can be answered. Also, SO is not code writing service, we are here to help with specific problems you encounter. Did you try writing this query, if so where are you stuck, what did you try etc...? Include that code in your question.

Comment: You can also read through [tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).

Comment: Hi, there is no code to post at the moment, this is a theoritical question, on how should I get started, how to plan the query. I have no idea how to approach this, since I need to group rows by node_id (i can do that) , order by idx(I can do that), then compare every 2 rows  (n, n+1) (don't know how), until I find the MAX diff on batt

Comment: Then this is not a right place to ask such a question. Research, watch tutorials, try, try again, research some more, try again after that, etc.. and in the end if you are still stuck, provide minimal, reproducible example, write what you tried, why it didn't work, provide code and then we can help you. As a tip look into [LAG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) function

Comment: So this IS a code writing place, since its only right for implementation specifics, and correcting errors in posted code. Programming theory, algotithms are out of scope?

Comment: I repeat SO is not a code writing service. It is not a place where you can come say what you need and expect you will get written code that solves your requirement.  [You can read through what is on topic in help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249472/discussion-between-aarlaneth-and-sagi2313).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LAG()` to peek at a previous row.

For example (assuming your table has the column `voltage` and `datetime`:

```
select * from (
  select t.*, lag(voltage) over(order by datetime) as prev_voltage from t
) x
where voltage > prev_voltage
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I am looking for, already tested a simple version, without grouping etc, and seems to work, Thank you!